# Não consigo carregar dados firebird no Delphi XE2 usando TZQuery

Tags: delphi, firebird

Tenho um TZQuery criado, e tento carregar os campos *SEQ_CTE* e *SERIE_CTE* conforme o código abaixo:

```
ZQuery1.sql.text :=
    'select * from C000004 where filial = '' + frmprincipal.spanel1.caption + ''';
  ZQuery1.open;
  ZQuery1.execsql;

  DBEdit2.text := ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SEQ_CTE').asstring;
  eserie.text := ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SERIE_CTE').asstring;

  showmessage(ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SERIE_CTE').asstring);

  ZQuery1.close;
```

A resposta que o sistema retorna, é um dado vazio, porém no banco de dados existem dados.
Alguém sabe como posso fazer para resolver isso?

Informação adicional: o código SQL está correto pois tentei gerar ele pelo delphi e então executar no firebird e retornou os dados corretamente.

Comment: o problema maior do código acima é que o comando `open` é o que você quer, ele executa o comando SQL e retorna os dados para o DataSet. o `execSql` é para SQL alterações de dados, que não retornam tuplas para o DataSet. Mesmo na resposta o ExecSql é desnecessário, e utilizar parâmetros foi uma boa solução

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui resolver de uma maneira bem interessante, que vi neste vídeo:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tp8D9tYRX34

Para resolver, fui na propriedade params do componentes e criei um chamado `Tfilial`

Na propriedade SQL coloquei o seguinte código: `select * from  C000004 where filial = :Tfilial`

O meu código delphi citado acima ficou assim:

```
ZQuery1.Params.ParamValues['Tfilial'] := frmprincipal.spanel1.caption;
  ZQuery1.execsql;
  ZQuery1.Active := true;

  DBEdit2.text := ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SEQ_CTE').asstring;
  eserie.text := ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SERIE_CTE').asstring;

  showmessage(ZQuery1.fieldbyname('SERIE_CTE').asstring);
```